# Start mocha chai test when app is a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

A very simplification of the code where the server starts asynchronously

```
// server/app.js
let appPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   [..async stuff..]
   const app = express()
   const server = http.createServer(app)
   server.listen(config.port, config.ip, () => {...}
})    
export default appPromise;
```

Where from I starts the tests:

```
// test/index.js
require('@babel/core').transform('code', {});
require('@babel/register');
let tests = require('./tests.js');

module.exports = {tests};
```

The code where tests are implemented:

```
// test/test.js
const app = require('../server/app')
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();
app.then(() => {
    describe(..tests...)
})
```

The error I get:

> `.then() is not a function`

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are using ES6 export, but not importing in the ES6 way.

Your import of "app" should be:

```
import appPromise from '../server/app';
```

Also, your promise in "app.js" doesn't seem to resolve anything, if that isn't an omission, you need to resolve something in your promise for **.then()** to work. Here is a working example:

```
const appPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('appPromise resolved');
});
```